# Passing parameters through scripting

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

Using Testcomplete (javascript) for our automation.

I have created a function:

```
function SelectDropdownBoxItem(object, property, item)
   {    
    var dropDown = eval(object + "." + FindChild(property, item, 5));
    dropDown.Click();
   }
```

Also tried without using eval...

When I call the method using something like this:

```
var AutoAddressSuggestionList = Aliases.b.pageGuidewireClaimc.panelBoundlist.AddressSuggestionList;

SelectDropdownBoxItem(AutoAddressSuggestionList,"contentText","1 Something Street*");
```

I get an error "Object Expected"...  I have no idea why, because when I run this method without parameterizing it everything works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `eval` here; you can call the method directly on the object:

```
var dropDown = object.FindChild(property, item, 5);
```

Also, it's a good idea to check that the list item was actually found:

```
if (dropDown.Exists) {
   dropDown.Click();
}
else {
   Log.Error(
     "Drop-down list item was not found.",
     "Object: " + object.FullName + "\r\n" +
     "Item : " + item
   );
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work as per my example above.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "did not work"? Do you get an error message (what does it say)? Does it click a different item?

Comment: 'object' is a reserved word. Use another name for the first parameter. I would use another word for the 'property' parameter as well.

Comment: @DmitryNikolaev: I believe it's not. [Reserved Words in VBScript 5.5 and JScript 5.5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216528). Also, `object` wouldn't conflict with the built-in `Object`, because JScript is case-sensitive.